# Get data entered in textfield from another class (android)

Tags: android, authentication

I want to pass the data from a class entered in textfield to another class. So I want to pass the data that I entered in Class A to Class B to Class B to textfield. I want to transfer the data entered in chipfield to another class.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity_layout);

        chipfield = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editChip);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your other class is an Activity of a Fragment, you can use an [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent).

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
i.putExtra("myValue", chipfield.getText().toString())
startActivity(i);
```

And retrieve the value in the second activity with :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras == null) {
    return;
}
// get data via the key
String value1 = extras.getString("myValue");
if (value1 != null) {
    // do something with the data
}
```

If you want to access the data from a Java class(a model class for example), you can declare the variable `static` and access it with `LoginActivity.myVariable`.

Best